# Gravity Forms conditional logic based on Address State?

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements, gravity-forms-plugin

I have built a list of counties in Georgia in a dropdown, but only want it to appear when Georgia is chosen as the state in the Address field above it. The issue is that this field is not given to me as an option in the conditional logic choices.  How can I display my County dropdown only if Georgia is chosen and then a single line text field if any other state is chosen?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the Address field in conditional logic.

From their [site](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Enable_Conditional_Logic):

> Remember, to use conditional logic, you will need to create a drop down, checkbox, single line text or multiple choice field.

So you will have to create all fields that come in the address field separately and then you can do the conditional logic on the States field.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Peter. I wonder if I could use jQuery to show or hide drop downs based on the State input?